# JAVASCRIPT Вернуть значение из асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

Есть следующий код:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("unique", function(value, element) {
                //rpc.callServer возвращает promise, потому как является асинхронной
                rpc.callServer('checkLogin', value).then((result) => {
                    //result return true or false
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
                //мне нужно получить здесь значение result из функции rpc.CallServer().then
            }, 'Error message');
```

Функция rpc.callServer является асинхронной, в .then получает boolean. Как мне передать это самое значение в родительскую функцию для того, чтобы вернуть его? Я не могу родительскую функцию сделать так же асинхронной, так как она является обработчиком (callback) и должна возвращать true/false.

Comment: никак. Скорее нужно смотреть как делать асинхронный валидатор.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но, по-моему jQuery validator поддерживает remote-методы. Возможно Вам как-то поможет эта страница http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method